# Bootstrap 3 Vertical Alignment Across Multiple Rows

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've came across a need to vertically align items across multiple rows. As it can be seen from the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fTFuftVeqL0a5ZzI0swb?p=preview) the Font Awesome icons aren't aligned with all the checkboxes below. How do I align the icons with the rows of checkboxes? There are more columns in the table those were removed for posting here. On the checkboxes there are margin-left and margin-right.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>F Trace</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

        <section id='top5'>
            <div class='container tables'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-12 settings'>
                        <table class="table text-center custom-table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="12%"><div>Инженерные системы</div><div class='controls'><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i><i class="fa fa-tint"></i><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i><i class="fa fa-yelp"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></div></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="vert-align checkboxes"><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="vert-align checkboxes"><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="vert-align checkboxes"><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: I'll mark the other answer as the accepted one. I have to continue coding the rest of the page so cannot create a fiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use icons of the same size. Or set the `div.controls i {width: 10px;}`

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7PldSOuMiNH6D2xMVYsq?p=preview)

Comment: Looks way better now! Thank you. If you don't mind could you please explain what {width: 10px;} changes?

Comment: It changes the width of all icons nested in your div class 'controls'.